# JButton cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I got an error on the line a JButton is on. Can someone help? It's really short code, by the way:

```
public class Main {
    public JButton[] grid = new JButton[9];
    public void init_components() {}
    public void init_icons() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need an appropriate 'import' statement in your source code to tell Java what 'JButton' means.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
```

An IDE, like Eclipse, will make it much easier for you to get started here.